# jQuery: Time table with current time

Tags: jquery, plugins, timetable

Is there some jQuery plugin to show a time table (monday to sunday) with hours and with a bar indicating the current time?

[Here's an example](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/99/timetablei.png/)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have to write your own I'm afraid. [Here is something to get you started](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/PnCrE/1/). I'm sure it's far from complete, but you should be able to build on it.

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed a start!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [jQuery Events Calendar](http://www.web-delicious.com/jquery-events-calendar-wdcalendar/)?

Comment: That one seemed nice, but it's a bit too crowded. it has to be simple since the hours are static, it will be to display the opening hours from a shop. It's not really a calendar sort, but more like a time table with static times.

Comment: so it won't have anything dynamic?

Comment: Well, depending on which day it is, the bars will be gray/colored.

And the black bar should indicate which time it is atm.

Comment: Try this one: https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar/wiki/demos is as simple as it gets for calendars. If it doesn't work for you, I fear you'll have to make it yourself

Comment: Hmm I'm afraid so then, because it's not really a calendar I'm looking for, as in the picture I provided i just want a table (which will always be the same. So rows from monday to sunday, and colums with the hours. And the vertical bar will indicate the current time. The difference with a calendar is that in a calendar you assign each day as an individual day, so monday 1st, monday the 8th, monday the 15th etc..